# Perl IPv6 address expansion/parsing

Tags: perl, ipv6

I have an address like `2001:db8::1` in a scalar, and would like to get the expanded form, `2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001`. Does the main Perl package ship - in its vast forest in `/usr/lib/perl5/...` - a module that will already do this? If not, does someone have a few lines that would do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CPAN has [`Net::IP`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-IP/IP.pm) which can do what you need.

Here's a transcript showing you it in action:

```
$ cat qq.pl
use Net::IP;
$ip = new Net::IP ('2001:db8::1');
print $ip->ip() . "\n";

$ perl qq.pl
2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
```

Comment: and `Net::IP` is pure-perl. I love pure-perl modules.

Comment: `$ip = Net::IP::ip_expand_address('2001:db8::1', 6);` will do for me, no need for the extra object.

Answer (score 4):

`Net::IP` is definitely a great way to go, because it's easy and powerful.  But, if you're going to parse tons of them you might consider using `inet_pton` from the `Socket` package instead, as it's 10-20 times faster than the `Net::IP` object version, even with the object pre-created.  And 4ish times faster than the `ip_expand_address` version:

```
use Net::IP;
use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday tv_interval);
use Socket qw(inet_pton AF_INET6);
use bignum;
use strict;

# bootstrap
my $addr = "2001:db8::1";
my $maxcount = 10000;

my $ip = new Net::IP($addr);

my ($t0, $t1);
my $res;

# test Net::IP
$t0 = [gettimeofday()];
for (my $i = 0; $i < $maxcount; $i++) {
    $ip->set($addr);
    $res = $ip->ip();
}
print "Net::IP elapsed:   " . tv_interval($t0) . "\n";
print "Net::IP Result:    $res\n";

# test non-object version
$t0 = [gettimeofday()];
for (my $i = 0; $i < $maxcount; $i++) {
    $res = Net::IP::ip_expand_address('2001:db8::1', 6);
}
print "ip_expand elapsed:  " . tv_interval($t0) . "\n";
print "ip_expand Result:   $res\n";

# test inet_pton
$t0 = [gettimeofday()];
for (my $i = 0; $i < $maxcount; $i++) {
    $res = join(":", unpack("H4H4H4H4H4H4H4H4",inet_pton(AF_INET6, $addr)));
}
print "inet_pton elapsed: " . tv_interval($t0) . "\n";
print "inet_pton result:  " . $res . "\n";
```

Running this on a random machine for me produced:

```
Net::IP elapsed:   2.059268
Net::IP Result:    2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
ip_expand elapsed: 0.482405
ip_expand Result:  2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
inet_pton elapsed: 0.132578
inet_pton result:  2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
```